# Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object global] is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '`$`' of object [object global] is not a function 
>   in line 2:

Using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
    $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});
```

The problem appears local at 127.0.0.1 only, while same code OK online!  I'm dazzled, any ideas?

Comment: line 2: is $(tabs.. ) of

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tabs > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
 $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});

Comment: It seems that jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: uhh now its also broken online while it was OK before...

Maybe this is a hint, Dev-Tools says:
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain
??

Comment: Ok added 
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">
to header and #JavaScript
addType application/x-javascript .js 
to .htaccess 
as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658238/debug-message-resource-interpreted-as-other-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appli 
but, No , not the case....

Comment: its very inconsistent: now local OK but online not, realy confuses me.. thanks for any replies OS.

Comment: problem solved: due to local/online ping-pong there was css online mising. Else Mime/Type header (see above) seemed have helped inconsistency. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

I ran into this error when I was trying to use the [slide effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) that I thought was part of jQuery but was actually a jQuery UI effect. This was the output from my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '#<Object>' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

So, to me it seems like you just need to include the jquery UI library. Add this line after you include jQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem. 5 minutes wasted :)

Comment: In my case it was a gremlin - a hidden character!

Answer (score 16):

Check to see if any other script you are using is calling [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Doing so releases the `$` binding, thus causing the `$` symbol to be undefined.

One way to fix this is to add `$` as the first parameter of your callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    ...
}
```

This works because the global jQuery object is passed as the first parameter to a `.ready()` handler. See also http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 11):

Use this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#tabs > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
    $('#featuredvid > ul').tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I had pretty much same problem. The error message says

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function() {
```

The line in my code that was throwing error is this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

In my case the problem is that $ is not recognized as jquery. I had to replace $ with the keyword jQuery. So finally i changed my code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with tabs and after some digging in jQuery documentation I found this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function

Once I overrode the jQuery it was working. So it seems like I had some namespace problems.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and solve it by adding

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

as a global var on my script

Answer (score 2):

Is jquery available locally ?  (the error you mention usually means that the jQuery is not available - loaded)

Perhaps you are loading it from a relative path and the structure is different to the online version ..

Comment: nope , the same absolute path using stg like
in header

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_option('siteurl') ?>/js/sprinkle.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Might be a browser security setting, blocking JS to run locally, are you using IE by any chance?
Try with Firefox or play with your security settings in IE

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use the following :

```
jQuery(function() {
    //Your code when document will be ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the version of jQuery or something along those lines. I had this exact problem - I was using a local copy of jQuery (version 1.3.2) and then switched to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js and suddenly it worked (latest at the time was 1.4.1).

I also had some of the issues you mentioned about "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain". I think that's safe to ignore for this particular problem as it still shows up for me even though my javascript is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the pop up blocker worked for me