# GWT/Twitter Bootstrap: Popover on GWT elements?

Tags: javascript, gwt, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Bootstrap popover on a TextBox from GWT.

```
<a href="#" class="btn danger" rel="popover" title="A title" data-content="some content...">hover for popover</a>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("a[rel=popover]").popover({
              offset: 10
    });
  })
</script>
```

like so:

```
TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "rel", "popover");
DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "title", "A Title");
DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "data-content", "Popover content...");
```

and then, in the `<head>` of my .html the `<script>` part mentioned above (with `$("input[rel=popover])...")`).

The required .js-files are linked to the html file via `<script src=...>`

But nothing happens when i hover the TextBox.

Some questions:

Is this restricted to `<a>`? Or am I loading the script files wrong? 
Is it even possible to add `rel=...` and `data-content=...` to a TextBox of GWT? Do I need jQuery/GQuery for that script snippet?

edit:

I tried what Strelok suggested and got the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): $ is not defined
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
at de.eikecochu.awidb.client.Awidb.bindBootstrapPopover(Awidb.java)
at de.eikecochu.awidb.client.Awidb.onModuleLoad(Awidb.java:11)
... 9 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been curious of integrating Bootstrap with GWT myself, but have not tried it. My guess is that if you are including `bootstrap-twipsy.js` and `bootstrap-popover.js` you also need to include jQuery on your page.

In addition to that you most likely need to call `$('xxx').popover(options)` *after* your text box is attached in GWT. So try something like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  final TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
  DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "rel", "popover");
  DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "title", "A Title");
  DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "data-content", "Popover content...");
  DOM.setElementAttribute(tb1.getElement(), "id", "test");
  tb1.addAttachHandler( new AttachEvent.Handler() {
    public void onAttach(AttachEvent e) {
      if (e.isAttached()) {
        bindBootstrapPopover(tb1.getElement().getId());
      }
    }
  });
  RootPanel.get().add(tb1);
}

native void bindBootstrapPopover(String id) /*-{
  $('#'+id).popover( {offset:10} );
}-*/;
```

Would be curious to hear how you go with this.

Comment: You have jQuery included in your page, right? Also try `$wnd.$('#'+id).popover( {offset:10} );`.

Answer (score 3):

Also, take a look at GWT-Bootstrap :)

It's under heavy development, but we has a lot of widgets ported and working.

take a look if you want: http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same thing as Eike, except with wrapping the bootstrap tooltip plugin.  Strelok's answer was a great help to me in this but there were two pieces that I had to figure out separately:

1. Make sure that the version of jQuery that you're using is copacetic
   with the twitter bootstrap plugins.  Currently (6/8/2012) that's >
   jQuery 1.7.1
2. If $wnd.$(...)... doesn't work try $wnd.jQuery, and see [this
   question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5382397/242135) for why ;)

Specifically I was getting this error:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```