# jQuery works on local host, but not on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebug, xampp

Using Notepad++ and XAMPP to test stuff, then I upload it to the website over FTP. In the head of my code, I have this to call jQuery and the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/portfolio.js"></script>
```

and it works fine locally on my XAMPP server. But as soon as it's uploaded onto the host, it throws this error:

```
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

Not sure what's going on, or why it's having a hard time using jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the file name "jQuery.js" is what messed it up. Locally, the uppercase 'U' wasn't an issue, but on the server it's what caused it to break. I didn't even know this could happen :-/

Comment: If you were developing on Windows, and deploying on Linux, case sensitivity would come into play.

Answer (score 4):

This is not specific to jQuery at all. When you load your page from the server, a request is sent to the web server to download `/jquery.js`. In the server's response, there is a HTTP header which gives a hint about the type of the file to the client. This is called the `Content-Type` header. The above error message says that the server reports (incorrectly) that `/jquery.js` is of type `text/html`, while it is not.

You have to modify the configuration of the remote web server to ensure that files with `.js` extension are properly reported as having `application/x-javascript` as their MIME type instead of `text/html`. This can be done by the following directive in an Apache configuration file:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

I'm not sure why your other `.js` file works, though. Anyway, if you cannot modify the web server config for any reason, you can try using an [externally hosted copy of jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) instead.

It might have also happened that you hit a bug in WebKit/Safari if you are using Safari on Mac OS X. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658238/debug-message-resource-interpreted-as-other-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appli).

Comment: So what do I do to fix it? The Portfolio.js file loads fine

Answer (score 0):

It means your server isn't configured to use the correct content-type for js files. It sends them as text/html instead of text/javascript. Probablyy the server aint configured right.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the google hosted version which a lot of people will probably already have cached and it always stays updated, etc..

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/