# Why does Chrome generate a warning when I inject my Tweet button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter

Why does this code generate a warning in Chrome?

```
$("<div><script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type='text/javascript'></script><a href='http://twitter.com/share?url=" + myUrl + "&amp;count=none&amp;text=" + myText + "' class='twitter-share-button'>Tweet</a></div>").insertBefore('#lastSection');
```

On the Chrome console I see this warning message:

```
Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
```

along with a reference to the right of the console pane:

```
count.json: -1
```

I tried moving the `script` reference to the `head` section of the page but that didn't help:

```
<script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

In fact, the tweet button didn't show up at all after I did that.

Comment: Your server is setting the MIME type of the script to "application/json", which is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Because Twitter are serving up JavaScript file (`http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=$SOMEURL&callback=twttr.receiveCount` with the content-type for JSON data.

They don't seem to realize that JSON-P is deserialized JSON embedded in a JavaScript function call (and thus to be served as application/javascript) and not pure JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you, seems like a bug.

[Debug message "Resource interpreted as other but transferred with MIME type application/javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658238/debug-message-resource-interpreted-as-other-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appli/658621#658621)

(possible dupe!)