# Why does Google Chrome 9 not show images from Amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, caching

If you go to this site, you'll notice a big image in the middle.
If you inspect it, you'll see this.

```
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mosaicimages/hmn58067pa">
```

If you hover over it during Inspect mode, you'll see this:

```
img[480x640]
```

And that's normal. The picture should display.

But sometimes, when I browse my site, the image simply does not display. The HTMl is the same. Everything is the same. It's just that the "cache" messes up.

This is what it looks like: http://i52.tinypic.com/1190xu0.jpg

When the image doesn't display, I clear the cache in Chrome browser settings, and the image displays again. After browsing the site again, random pictures disappear.

It's weird because when you inspect it, the code is the same. However, the image says:

```
img[0x0]
```

That's very awkward, because the image really is there.  it's in S3 and it's fine.
It happens on other pages as well, not just this page. It happens for all images that are in S3.

Some of you may not be able to reproduce it. Some of my friends reproduce it.  but if you can, please help, thanks.

Edit: I found a few bug issues related to Chrome? Is this it?

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67373&can=1&q=image%20304&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68622

Edit: everything works fine in incognito mode.

Comment: Either fortunately, or unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this issue (Though, I am running Chrome 10). Perhaps it has to do with your browser settings? Additionally: Does this issue occur with any other browsers, or is it specific to Chrome 9?

Comment: Are you using Chrome 9? By the way, this issue does not happen in Firefox

Comment: My friend who is running the latest chrome 9 latest developer build, also has this problem. It's really random. Some images show up some just have img[0x0] when you inspect it. I'm using "9.0.597.84" THat's what it says in About Chrome. Weirdly enough, my friend says "9.0.597.84 Beta"

Comment: I have seen this problem in chrome and I do believe its the browser problem. What happens when you clear cache or do hard refresh? Does the image reappear.

Comment: @doc_180. When I clear the cache or SHIFT +refresh, everything is fine and the image shows. After browsing a little, things mess up again and the image doesn't show.

Comment: @mu, it doesn't matter if I include width or height, the image doesn't show

Comment: Is this a programming problem - or should this question belong on one of the other stackexchange sites?

Comment: I believe we have considerable amount of information now. There are more than one bug reported on this and I have further questions. Does this happen only with images hosted in amazon s3? ( may be some cache setting in the response header). 2. The fact that it works in incognito tells me that there is some configuration flag that could help. Could you create a new profile in chrome ( after backing up your old profile).

Comment: I don't see the problem in Chrome9 at all

Comment: It's happening on a small site I created for a client too. No S3 involved. Was working with Chrome 8. Works in all my other browsers. Seems to be issue with Chrome 9.

Comment: Happens on http://imgfave.com in chrome 9 (newest stable and beta release)

Comment: This bug has been driving me nuts. It is NOT specific to S3, it happens with images hosted locally on Mongrel and WEBrick as well as on my production Apache2 server. Clearing cache and refreshing will load the image. Hardcoding a width and height reveals this interesting bit when inspecting img[100 x 100 pixels (Natural 0 x 0 pixels)]. This is most definitely a browser issue...

Comment: I've gotten this with chrome 10, with identical symptoms.

Comment: would help to get the link to your website back again

Answer (score 2):

Do you get the following warning in the console?

```
Resource interpreted as [something] but transferred with MIME type [something else]
```

It may happen if an image is loaded dynamically (i.e. img src changed at runtime on the client) - which was nicely responded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542433/1081234).

This *could* also be caused by the browser actually receiving an incorrect MIME type declaration - I don't imagine that would be an S3-specific issue (given the apparently [wide range](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OsmsL2-_EP8) of similar problems encountered) and would rather suggest it could be an issue with a forwarding (corporate?) proxy etc. - this was the case for us when including fonts but never with images.

Answer (score -1):

Google chrome has an excellent report issue located in the settings tab, take this issue to them,atleast they will rectify in future release chrome versions.