# Content-Type is correct by still getting "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css."?

Tags: css, apache2

I'm getting the following warning for a one of css files in my installation:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css.
```

How to solve this problem? 
I'm running apache2 with ruby on rails 2.8.11.

The server is definitely sending the correct content type:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:803
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 15 Jun 2011 04:20:45 GMT
ETag:"66941-921-49f967c2bd200"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=96
Last-Modified:Tue, 29 Mar 2011 03:16:24 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

But still, browser is claiming that "resource is interpreted as Image".

Comment: How are you embedding the CSS?

Comment: Could this question/answer be it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658238/debug-message-resource-interpreted-as-other-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appli There's a couple options on there. My favorite was <img src=""> causing something similar... I suspect your problem is with your HTML, so you might want to post that for the page that generates that warning message

Comment: So, did you check if the file is actually an image?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by fixing one of my CSS files.
I changed the code:

```
body { background:url(''); }
```

For:

```
body { background-image:none; }
```

---

**Explanation:**
Since `url('')` points to itself, and it is a `.css` file, the browser couldn't find the image it was looking for to fill `url`.